# Javascript function confusion

Tags: javascript

Firstly, sorry for the not specific title. I don't know how to call this.

Ok, here goes my question.

I am going to take Javascript's reduce function here.

I know the "reduce" function is defined as follows

```
function reduce(array, combine, start) {
  var current = start;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    current = combine(current, array[i]);
  return current;
}
```

Well, what I don't understand is this.

Why

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}, 0);
```

and

```
reduce([1, 2, 3, 4], function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}, 0);
```

returns the same result of "10"?

I know how the function works. I just don't understand why

- xx.functionABC(param2,param3)

  is the same as
- functionABC(param1,param2,param3)

Thanks for the reply everyone!

---

Thanks for all the comments and answers!

I feel stupid for not checking with other methods first (or shouldn't try with a built in function).

Comment: The `array.reduce` is a [built-in function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for Arrays.

Comment: To extend the comment above. You have defined your own reduce function. But `reduce` function is also part of the `array`'s prototype. It was just coincidence that both work.

Comment: (After your edit) They are not the same, they *do* the same. This will not work with any random function.

Comment: @Jongware, I get it. You should put as answer as I feel thats the best answer so far (I immediately understood what a stupid question this was)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code snippet is using `Array.prototype.reduce`, and the second snippet is using your custom `reduce` function.

They happen to be implemented mostly the same, and therefore give the same result.

Here is an example of how they are different. `Array.prototype.reduce` passes additional arguments to the combine callback, namely the current array index, and a reference to the array itself. Your function does not pass these arguments.

```js
function reduce(array, combine, start) {
  var current = start;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    current = combine(current, array[i]);
  return current;
}

function foo(a, b, i) { return a + b * i; };

console.log([1, 2, 3, 4].reduce(foo, 0));

console.log(reduce([1, 2, 3, 4], foo, 0));
```

<sup>(See the developer console of your browser for the result.)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helped me understand what was wrong with my question.
well, after your edit, I don't understand what you meant by "Array.prototype.reduce passes additional arguments to the combine callback, namely the current array index, and a reference to the array itself. Your function does not pass these arguments."

Comment: Read the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) documentation, where it says the callback is "Function to execute on each value in the array, taking **four arguments**". Also see the code to implement it, where it does `value = callback(value, t[k], k, t);`

Answer (score 0):

There is has a method `Array.prototype.reduce()` in js. It means method belongs to the Array.prototype. But there is no simple function `reduce()`. Probably you use the some library provide it.